# when i use seo friendly url then got 404 error in php

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

when i run my website in local host then my website is running

when i run my website online then got error

Server Error

> 404 - File or directory not found.
>   The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

htaccess file contain

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^home?$ index.php
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ category.php?Id=$1&category=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ post_details.php?cat=1&postid=$2&post=$3 [L]
```

please help

Comment: i assume you are using a web hosting service, and you are using windows for your local host, is that correct? if yes, then it might be because of the unix/linux file system in your hosting, in unix, file names are case sensitive, meaning that in your hosting, `http://server.com/Hello.php` is not the same as `http://server/hello.php`, so check for case inconsistency in your code

Answer (score 0):

write this code in .htaccess file -

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?p=profile&id=$1
```

this will work like -

Should work for:

```
www.example.com/index.php?p=profile&id=20

to

www.example.com/profile/20/profile-friendly-name
```